# Collaborate with colleagues who don’t use git

Tags: git

While I use git for all of my projects, occasionally, I have to collaborate with colleagues who don’t use git. They prefer to email their zipped sources back and forth. It’s annoying and cumbersome, but I have to deal with it. The workflow is as follows:

When they need my code, I use `git archive` and send them a Zip file `export.zip`. I continue to work and commit the changes I do, while they work with my outdated sources. Illustration:

```
   ┌ archive & mail
   │
   A ← B ← C
       └───┴── my later changes
```

Some time later, they send me their response file `import.zip`. **What’s the best way to import the Zip file into my git tree and how to implement it?** I can think of the following three options, which differ semantically:

1. Consider my later changes based on their changes:

   ```
      ┌ archive & mail
      │
      A ← A' ← B ← C
          │    └───┴── my later changes
          │  
          └─ their changes
   ```

   Here I would checkout `A`, unzip `import.zip`, commit as `A'` and then reapply `B` and `C` (and whatever followed). How do I reapply commits up to `HEAD`?
2. Consider their changes based on my later changes:

   ```
   A ← B ← C ← A'
   ```

   Here I would create a patch based on the diff between `A` and `import.zip` and apply that to `C`.
3. Create a branch and merge:

   ```
   A ← B ← C ← M
      ↖     ↙
         A'
   ```

   While writing this question, I came to the conclusion that this option is the most generally applicable and the most robust. Do you agree?

I’m grateful for other advice regarding that workflow as well. For example, I find it tedious and error-prone to remember the commit `A` that I archived.

Comment: @aelam you might say that disparagingly, but there's a good chance that they in fact aren't software engineers.

Comment: Just as a note, you can reapply commits to another branch using `git rebase`, but I'd really recommend option #3.

Comment: have you tried rebase if you want all commits on a single line and also you can A->

Comment: My colleagues are indeed no software engineers, but researchers in an applied science. It’s difficult to convince someone to use git, if they already roll their eyes when you ask them to open the console. It’s unfortunate that, in academia, people often aren’t taught the tools they use, or rely on, every day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, #3 is the best.  I would create a branch for each person who might send you changes.  Checkout their branch, unzip the archive, and commit the changes into their branch.  At some point you can merge your changes together with their changes, and git will point out conflicts for you, which is obviously not optimal but relatively OK considering you're dealing with folks mailing zips around.  When you are ready to send them your most recent changes, I would recommend tagging the commit that you are archiving as "`collab-zip-<date>`" or something, with a tag message that says "Sending changes to X because Y".  That answers your last bit about how to keep track of what you sent, when.

Comment: I think I’ll go with this approach. It allows for multiple parallel collaborations as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I find it tedious and error-prone to remember the commit `A` that I archived.

Make an `export` branch, and do your work on a different branch. Whenever you're ready to send to your colleagues, you can just merge your latest to `export` and archive that. I'd suggest using this in conjunction with option #3.

And you also forgot option #4: convince your colleagues to use Git by offering to help them set up and get started with it. Teach a man to fish, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As other people already pointed out, #3 is the second-best* solution. It is roughly the same as when they would be using Git, too, only then you'd be merging remote branches instead of local ones, and they'd probably have multiple commits instead of just one.

You could of course rebase your commits on top of their changes (as per your first option), but then you would be rewriting history which would introduce a whole lot of other problems.

I would really not suggest using manual patches (option #2). Git has a very good `merge` tool that is designed for these situations.

*: The best solution is still to convince your colleagues to start using Git. Right now you are spending a lot of time and effort because of their *preferences*. If they're not willing to listen to you, simply talk with your boss and say him that you're wasting a lot of time because of their stubbornness, and that it comes with a higher risk of introducing bugs, and that (well I guess you can come up with some more arguments to convince him that it'll save some money).